# Plugin RegisterUrlRulesEvent - cannot find Controller aciton -> 404

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugins, migration

The error I'm getting:

```
HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
Page not found.
↵
Caused by: Invalid Route – yii\base\InvalidRouteException
Unable to resolve the request "Expedweather/forecast-panel".
```

The plugin's base was made through https://pluginfactory.io, I've simply added to it.

Below are the relevant code excerpts which for some reason do not seem to work as intended.

```php
// ./src/Expedweather.php::init
$map_page = 'data\/<range:\w+>\/<peak:\w+>\/<view:\w+>\/<parameter:\w+>';
$event->rules[$map_page] = 'expedweather/forecast-panel';
// ./src/controllers/DefaultController
protected $allowAnonymous = ['index', 'forecast-panel'];
public function actionForecastPanel() {...}
```

Any ideas and/or potential solutions?
The Regex routing seems to work fine, but it cannot find the DefaultController's Action.

This is on CraftCMS Version `3.3.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Found a Solution

#### Context:

When I created my plugin-frame through https://pluginfactory.io the **DefaultController was still a thing** -> routing to /pluginname/default-controller-action-name worked as it defaulted to search in the... default-controller. But it seems that is no more, 
so what I had to do instead to get it to find the action is add a section referring to the controller.

#### this is the new/fixed code:

```php
// ./src/Expedweather.php::init
$map_page = 'data\/<range:\w+>\/<peak:\w+>\/<view:\w+>\/<parameter:\w+>';
$event->rules[$map_page] = 'expedweather/default/forecast-panel'; // <-- changed!!
// ./src/controllers/DefaultController
protected $allowAnonymous = ['index', 'forecast-panel'];
public function actionForecastPanel() {...}
```

The only row that changed is the `$event->rules` one which now has **/default/** before the action -> this refers to the DefaultController.